# Display the employee detail with department name of given Fname if he is accountant

Tags: oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper, plsql-package

input from
tblemp(empid number primary key,
fname varchar2(20),
lname varchar2(20),
jdate date, salary number,
mid number,
post varchar2(20),
did varchar2(10) references tbldept1 (did)) ;

tbldept1(did varchar2(10) primary key,dname varchar2(10));

Write a pl/sql block of code to Display the employee detail with department name of given Fname if he is accountant.

i am try it for two method but still i am get error .

first method in this code by using type function:

```
declare
    type temp is record (
    veid tblemp1.empid%type,
    vfname tblemp1.fname%type,
    vlname tblemp1.lname%type,
    vsalary tblemp1.salary%type,
    vmid tblemp1.mid%type,
    vjdate tblemp1.jdate%type,
    vpost tblemp1.post%type,
    vdid tblemp1.did%type,
    vdname tbldept.dname%type);
    remp temp;
    remp1 temp;

begin
    select empid,fname,lname,salary,mid,jdate,post,d.did,dname into remp from tblemp1 e,tbldept d where e.did=d.did and empid=&empid;

    select empid,fname,lname,salary,mid,jdate,post,d.did,dname into remp1 from tblemp1 e,tbldept d where e.did=d.did and e.post='Accountant';

        dbms_output.put_line('empid = '||remp.empid);
        dbms_output.put_line('fname = '||remp.fname);
        dbms_output.put_line('lname = '||remp.lname);
        dbms_output.put_line('jdate = '||remp.jdate);
        dbms_output.put_line('mid = '||remp.mid);
        dbms_output.put_line('post = '||remp.post);
        dbms_output.put_line(' did = '||remp.did);
        dbms_output.put_line(' salary = '||remp.salary);
        dbms_output.put_line(' dname = '||remp1.dname);

end;
/
```

second method is by using row type function using

```
declare
    remp tblemp1%rowtype;
    remp1 tbldept%rowtype;  

begin
    select * into remp from tblemp1 where empid=&empid and post='Accountant';

    select * into remp1 from tbldept ;

        dbms_output.put_line('empid = '||remp.empid);
        dbms_output.put_line('fname = '||remp.fname);
        dbms_output.put_line('lname = '||remp.lname);
        dbms_output.put_line('jdate = '||remp.jdate);
        dbms_output.put_line('mid = '||remp.mid);
        dbms_output.put_line('post = '||remp.post);
        dbms_output.put_line(' did = '||remp.did);
        dbms_output.put_line(' salary = '||remp.salary);
        dbms_output.put_line(' dname = '||remp1.dname);

end;
/
```

i am try it with two method .
im try it till morning but untill i am not getting output.

my prectical exam pass come so plaese help me.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't sure if your table names were correct (your code didn't match your question text), but if you fix them, then your code looks reasonable to me

```
SQL> create table tbldept1(did varchar2(10) primary key,dname varchar2(10));

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> create table tblemp(empid number primary key, fname varchar2(20), lname varchar2(20),
  2  jdate date, salary number, mid number, post varchar2(20), did varchar2(10) references tbldept1 (did)) ;

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> insert into tbldept1 values (10,'Accounts');

1 row created.

SQL> insert into tblemp values (1000,'Jane','Doe',sysdate,1000,1001,'Accountant',10);

1 row created.

SQL>
SQL>
SQL> set serverout on
SQL> declare
  2      remp tblemp%rowtype;
  3      remp1 tbldept1%rowtype;
  4
  5  begin
  6      select * into remp from tblemp where empid=&empid and post='Accountant';
  7
  8      select * into remp1 from tbldept1 ;
  9
 10          dbms_output.put_line('empid = '||remp.empid);
 11          dbms_output.put_line('fname = '||remp.fname);
 12          dbms_output.put_line('lname = '||remp.lname);
 13          dbms_output.put_line('jdate = '||remp.jdate);
 14          dbms_output.put_line('mid = '||remp.mid);
 15          dbms_output.put_line('post = '||remp.post);
 16          dbms_output.put_line(' did = '||remp.did);
 17          dbms_output.put_line(' salary = '||remp.salary);
 18          dbms_output.put_line(' dname = '||remp1.dname);
 19
 20  end;
 21  /
Enter value for empid: 1000
old   6:     select * into remp from tblemp where empid=&empid and post='Accountant';
new   6:     select * into remp from tblemp where empid=1000 and post='Accountant';
empid = 1000
fname = Jane
lname = Doe
jdate = 22-MAR-22
mid = 1001
post = Accountant
did = 10
salary = 1000
dname = Accounts

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Comment: i am doing same but sql saw error:ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01403: no data found
ORA-06512: at line 6

Comment: that means you don't have data in the tables (or at least data that matches your criteria)